# Using JSON.parse for accessing a json file

Tags: json, jquery

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('dat.js', function(data) {
         var obj = JSON.parse(data);
         alert(obj[0].title);
    });
});
```

My JSON file :

```
{
    "posts": 
    [
        {
        "title": "ajax | Programming ",
        "url": "hello"
        },
        {
        "title": "jQuery and Ajax Demos Pard - 3",
        "url": "how are you"
        },
    ]
}
```

Its giving me an error `JSON.parse:unexpected character`. But when I tried to do it by taking the json inside an array its ok then. I want to access the data from json file itself

Comment: It's the extra comma character after the last post object, after "how are you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do parseJSON when your input is a json string and u expect an object. Here, getJSON is already giving u the response as an object.

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('dat.js', function(obj) {
         alert(obj.posts[0].title);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A Quick jslint check says that you have invalid json at line 11 `},`, Try removing the comma from the last member of "posts" and see if that help

```
            {
            "title": "jQuery and Ajax Demos Pard - 3",
            "url": "how are you"
            }, <---- THIS
```

Comment: are you able to give me the link to the page's url?

Comment: but when i attach the same in json its not working JSON.parse:unexpected charecter.

Comment: can you try inspecting the response from chrome's console? See if your server returns any funky characters